# How to get column by filter key in p:dataTable

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2, primefaces-datatable

Is there any way how to get column instace by **filter key**? Suppose you have

```
<p:column headerText="Something" filterBy="#{car.id}" filterMatchMode="contains">
```

By calling `DataTable#getFilters()` you will obtain map containing entry `{id=...}` where `id` is variable's property name. How can I get column by **property name** (in this particular case by `id`)?

**MOTIVATION**

To build sql query from provided filters where `filterMatchMode` need to be provided in order to write the right `LIKE` expression for given condition. So I would like to get these pairs:

```
List<WhereFilter> whereFilters = new LinkedList<>();

for (Entry<String,Object> filter : dataTable.getFilters()) {
    String propertyName = filter.getKey(); // if value="#{car.id}", then property = "id"
    UIColumn c = dataTable.getSomehowColumnByFilterId(propertyName); // HOW?
    String matchMode = c.getFilterMatchMode();
    whereFilters.add(new WhereFilter(filter, matchMode));
}
String query = buildQuery(whereFilters, SqlDialect.HQL);
```

One solution can be to use `headerText="propertyName"`, since `c.getHeaderText()` matches `filter.getKey()`, I would be able to find `c.getFilterMatchMode()`. The drawback is obvious - hardcoding property names in element is generally bad practice - renaming of entity's properties would require to rename also column headers. Moreover, property names are not suitable for displaying ("phoneNumber" vs "Phone number").

Comment: What do you want to achieve? I sort of not understand your question fully.

Comment: @Kukeltje I have updated my question (see motivation part).

Comment: ok, let me think about this tomorrow. I might have a solution but want to try this myself.

Comment: Is 'car' actually removed from the key? So just id remains? Or is there access to the complete car.id?

Comment: @Kukeltje yes, 'car' is removed, only 'id' alone is mapped as filter key.

Comment: What is your pf version?

Comment: @Kukeltje pf version 6.2.5.